# Is this algebra allowed

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Given

$$\frac{\frac{a}{a+b}}{\frac{c}{c+d}} = 1.8 \text{ (1)}$$

and

$$\frac{a}{a+b}-\frac{c}{c+d} = \frac{2}{15} \text{ (2)}$$

and

$a = 30$

and

$a+b+c+d=220 \text{ (3)}$

Solve the remaining

---

This is what I did

According to $(1)$ $$\frac{a}{a+b} = 1.8 \frac{c}{c+d}$$

$$\Leftrightarrow \frac{5}{9} \cdot \frac{a}{a+b} = \frac{c}{c+d}$$

then using $(2)$

$$\frac{a}{a+b} - \frac{c}{c+d} = \frac{2}{15}$$

$$\frac{30}{30+b} - \frac{5 \times 30}{9(30+b)} = \frac{2}{15} \implies b = 70$$

using $(3)$

$(30+70) + (c+d) = 220 \implies (a+c) = 120$

going back to $(2)$

$$\frac{a}{a+b} - \frac{c}{c+d} = \frac{2}{15}$$

$$\frac{3}{10} - \frac{c}{120} = \frac{2}{15} \implies c = 20, d = 100$$

Therefore : $a = 30, b = 70, c = 20, d = 100$

Confused if some of these algebra isn't allowed like rearranging then using it in another equation like:

$$\frac{c}{c+d} = \frac{5}{9} \times  \frac{a}{a+b}$$

in the initial step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is perfectly fine. Giving fractional algebraic values to another variable fraction is as good as substituting non-fractional variables such as $p=q$. You can always do this unless the denominator equals $0$.